# What is the correct term (preferably a noun) to describe the amount of time spent on practicing an instrument?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

For video games, I think *played time* is the general phrase to say how much time someone has spent on playing a game. For example, player A has accumulated 2000 hours of played time. For pilot, I think it's *flight time*. For example, commercial pilot requires 4 months of flight time to obtain a license. What about musicians? What is a short concise noun to describe the amount of time someone has spent on deliberately practicing an instrument?

I considered *played time* because musicians typically say "I play piano" or "I play guitar". What about vocalists? They don't say "I play voice". Is *practiced time* an appropriate choice here? Thank you

Comment: Your noun phrases need to be reversed: *time played, time practiced*, etc. The versions you have advanced are not grammatical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Musicians say,
*"I did 10 hours' practice today"* or *"It'll take three weeks' practice"* or *"That piece took 8 hours' practice a day for two weeks. That's a total of 56 hours' practice.*"

There's no equivalent of "flight time" (or "flight hours") because musicians usually start as children. They have no record of their *total* hours.

"Practiced time" isn't colloquial.

"Practice time" is used in, for example, *"I'd like to book 3 hours' practice time please,"* or *"It's ten o'clock. Practice time!"*

Ensembles and orchestras *rehearse*, but on your own you *practice.* (Btw, you *practise* in the UK.)

Answer (score 1):

Why not go with **rehearsal time** ?

Merriam-Webster defines **rehearsal** as

> a practice exercise : TRIAL

Makes sense then to call time spent on rehearsal as **rehearsal time.**

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but what if other people interpret it as the time to rehearse? e.g. it's rehearsal time this Saturday and it's show time this Sunday.